# Where should I place my php script file for AJAX request in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a form in my index file in my theme folder.

[image]

I also have the script called find-locations-ajax.php in the same theme folder which Im trying to call. When I try to call the script file it keeps loading the entire site.

Here is my code

```
jQuery(function($) {
$.ajax({
url:'find-locations-ajax.php',
type:'POST',
data:querystring,
success: function(msg){
}//ends success code

});//ends ajax
})//ends submit handler
});//ends ready function
```

First time working in wordpress so please go easy on me.

EDIT. This is not for ADMIN functionalities

[image]

New edit:
[image]

Comment: WP has it's own way you can use Ajax that might make it easier: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing AJAX a bit wrong for WordPress.
WordPress got a file to handle all of the AJAX requests, called `admin-ajax.php` and actions, to which you should bind your code to process these requests.
I suggest you read up [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to get some understanding.

Comment: So I setup my functions in the admin-ajax.php file. I ran a test and it runs good with the documentation you provided. Just wondering why I have to use the admin-ajax.php file even though its nothing relating to admin functionalities. Check the image I provided for you to see.\

Comment: @Carlitos I was wondering the same thing when I started coding for wordpress all these years ago and I still have no clue why they decided to make it this way tbh. This question should probably be addressed to authors of WP :)

Comment: so I did a bit more testing & research and found my ajax calls wont work if im not logged in as admin. I moved my functions in the same theme folder as where im making ajax requests. I just took the same format on how ajax makes calls.

Comment: @Carlitos there are two hooks for call processors. `wp_ajax_` for logged in users  and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` for non logged users. How exactly your calls are not working? Call returns 0? You get some js error?

Comment: Yeah I didnt know that lol. I kinda went off track but it still works. So now i have both files in the same theme folder. The code to call the request lives in the index.php file and the file to handle the request is called find-locations-ajax.php. In the find-locations-ajax.php I make a request to Google Places API and display the information on my index file. I updated an image to see.

Comment: `find-locations-ajax.php` just contains hook handlers, right?